# How to handle multiple Observable propertes in Obsever Pattern?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have a class A that implement Observable. And a class B that implement Observer. B (my observer) need to observe more than one properties of A and act differently based on the propery changed. How can I handle this?

I thinked to add an enum that represent the edited properties (lets call it ObservableObjectType) and edit the Observable/Observer interface in order to pass it to the Observer in the notifyObserver.

```
public interface Observer {   
public void update(ObservableObjectType type, Object obj);
}

public interface Observable {
public void AddObserver(Observer observer);
public void RemoveObserver(Observer observer);
public void Notify(ObservableObjectType type, Object obj);
}

public enum ObservableObjectType {FOO,BAR,FOOBAR}
```

So that in my class A when something change I could pass the ObservableObjectType

```
public class A implements Observable{

private X foo;
private X bar;
private Z foobar;

...

public setFoo(x){
this.foo=x;
this.Notify(ObservableObjectType.FOO, x);
}

public setBar(x){
this.bar=x;
this.Notify(ObservableObjectType.BAR, x);
}

public setFoobar(x){
this.foobar=x;
this.Notify(ObservableObjectType.FOOBAR, x)
}
```

And my observer class B has an update method like:

```
public void update(ObservableObjectType type, Object obj) {
    switch(type) {
    case FOO:
        //something
        break;
    case BAR:
        //something else
        break;
    case FOOBAR:
        //again something else
        break;
    }
```

I think that this is an horrible way of handle this problem, because of the ugly extendibility of the code above, if in the future I'll need to add another parameter to observe I'll have to first add that in the enum, and don't seem to be very elegant as a code.

I tought either to pass only the object type, and check in the update method with an `instance of` but if I have to do 2 different behaviour for the same type of object? Like in the example above the variable *foo* and *bar*.

Any advice? Probably I didn't understand very well the Observer Pattern.

Comment: The java.bean package has several classes that might be useful to you and might prevent reinventing the wheel.  Specifically start with a look at java.bean.PropertyChangeSupport https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This will save me tons of time!